# Функция для инициализации объекта в TypeScript

Tags: typescript, инициализация

Есть класс с большим количеством полей.
Я хочу написать универсальную функцию, которая бы инициализировала объекты любых классов.
Поля number инициализировала бы 0, строки = '', логический тип в false

```
function fillObject(obj: object) {
    for (let key in obj) {
        let value = obj[key as keyof object]
        if (typeof value == 'boolean'){
            obj[key as keyof object] = false
        }else if (typeof value == 'number'){
            obj[key as keyof object] = 0
        }else if (typeof value == 'string'){
            obj[key as keyof object] = ''
        }
    }
}
```

Но VSCode подсвечивает ошибку на строках с присвоением значений:
Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'

Как в TS написать такую функцию?

Comment: Никак. И, скорее всего, ненужно потому что непонятно какую проблему должна решать эта функция

Comment: Проще и производительнее будет написать инициализацию прямо в классе. Там же всё равно типы описаны, так что несложно дописать `count: number = 0; name: string = '';` и т.п.

Comment: в каком виде у вас будет поступать объект в эту функцию. Не совсем понятно. Если он будет наполненный - то вам нужно будет все сбросить на дефолт??

Comment: ` obj[key as keyof object] = false` для чего приведение типов?

Comment: если написать obj[key] = false - то TS тоже покажет ошибку.

Comment: @AlexeyD какую? странно но у меня не показывает. Может настройки линтера?

Comment: Проблема, которую должна решать эта функция: когда я пишу let obj: TMyObj - то obj = undefined. И мне нужно чтобы obj стал объектом, с заполненными полями, и потом просто изменить значение одного поля. Т.е. написать что то вроде: let obj: TMyObj ;  fillObj(obj);  obj.field1 = 5

Comment: Vitaliy Stop_RU_war_in_UA,  текст ошибки: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{}'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{}'

Comment: Если у вашей переменной есть класс `TMyObj ` - то почему нельзя определить у него конструктор и потом в коде писать ` let obj: TMyObj = new TMyObj()`?

Comment: Ну или создайте функцию, которая вернет начальный объект. Описанная вами конструкция не отработает, т.к. вы хотите в функцию передать undefined

Comment: Спасибо. Действительно, нужно сделать через конструктор.